# Delete all the nodes from a list that respect a condition influenced by another list

Tags: c, list

I am studying the lists and I came across this exercise which asks me to do the following steps:

Define a function that, given two lists of integers L1 and L2, and an integer n>0, eliminate from the first list the nodes for which the sum of the contents of L1 and L2 in the corresponding position (with respect to the original positions) is a multiple of n. If L2 ends, consider only the content of L1 instead of the sum.

I tried to analyze the problem with a single list and in this case I had no problems, but in this specific case I couldn't figure out how to proceed.

my problem is that I can't understand how properly build the various cases (L1 must be always != NULL, so I have: L1 != NULL && L2 != NULL or L1 != NULL && L2 == NULL).

Can someone explain to me the procedure to be performed and where am I wrong?

This is my attempt:

```
    struct data
    {
       int d;
       struct data *next;
    };

    typedef struct data Nodo;
    typedef Nodo *LIST;


    void function(LIST *l1, LIST l2, int n)
    {
      LIST p, head_1, head_2;

        while((*l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL)&&((*l1)->d + l2->d) % n == 0)
        {
           p = *l1;
           *l1 = (*l1)->next;
           free(p);
        }

        while((*l1 != NULL) && ((*l1)->d + l2->d) % n == 0)
        {
            p = *l1;
            *l1 = (*l1)->next;
            free(p);    
        }

        if (*l1 != NULL)
        {
           head_1 = *l1;
           head_2 = l2;

           while(head_1->next != NULL)
           {
              if (((head_1->next->d + head_2->next->d) % n) == 0)
              {
                p = head_1->next;
                head_1->next = head_1->next->next;
                free(p);
              }
              else
              {
                head_1 = head_1->next;
                head_2 = head_2->next;
              }
           }
         }
      }
```

Example:

L1: 4->4->11->3->4->8->7->NULL

L2: 5->1->5->1->5

OUTPUT(L1): 4->4->4->7->NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem of logic with the consecutive loops :

> ```
> while((*l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL)&&((*l1)->d + l2->d) % n == 0) {
>   ...
> }
> while((*l1 != NULL) && ((*l1)->d + l2->d) % n == 0){
>   ...
> }
> ```

if the sum of the elements are not a multiple of *n* you need to move to the next element, but you do not do

Out of that to hide a pointer with a *typedef* like you do with `typedef Nodo *LIST;` is *dangerous* and is a good way to introduce problem, I recommend you to never do that.

You can do that :

```
void removeIf(Nodo ** l1, Nodo * l2, int n)
{
  while ((*l1 != NULL) && (l2 !=  NULL)) {
    if ((((*l1)->d + l2->d) % n) == 0) {
      /* cell must be removed */
      Nodo * rm = *l1;

      *l1 = (*l1)->next;
      free(rm);
    }
    else {
      /* cell not removed */
      l1 = &(*l1)->next;
    }

    l2 = l2->next;
  }

  // case where l2 is shorter than l1
  while (*l1 != NULL) {
    if (((*l1)->d % n) == 0) {
      /* cell must be removed */
      Nodo * rm = *l1;

      *l1 = (*l1)->next;
      free(rm);
    }
    else {
      /* cell not removed */
      l1 = &(*l1)->next;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Making a full program for

- L1: 4->4->11->3->4->8->7
- L2: 5->1->5->1->5
- N : 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
  int d;
  struct data *next;
};

typedef struct data Nodo;

void removeIf(Nodo ** l1, Nodo * l2, int n)
{
  while ((*l1 != NULL) && (l2 !=  NULL)) {
    if ((((*l1)->d + l2->d) % n) == 0) {
      /* cell must be removed */
      Nodo * rm = *l1;

      *l1 = (*l1)->next;
      free(rm);
    }
    else {
      /* cell not removed */
      l1 = &(*l1)->next;
    }

    l2 = l2->next;
  }

  // case where l2 is shorter than l1
  while (*l1 != NULL) {
    if (((*l1)->d % n) == 0) {
      /* cell must be removed */
      Nodo * rm = *l1;

      *l1 = (*l1)->next;
      free(rm);
    }
    else {
      /* cell not removed */
      l1 = &(*l1)->next;
    }
  }
}

Nodo * make(int v, Nodo * n)
{
  Nodo * r = malloc(sizeof(Nodo));

  r->d = v;
  r->next = n;
  return r;
}

void del(Nodo ** pl)
{
  while (*pl != NULL) {
    Nodo * n = *pl;

    *pl = (*pl)->next;
    free(n);
  }
}

int main()
{
  Nodo * l1 = make(4, make(4, make(11, make(3, make(4, make(8, make(7, NULL)))))));
  Nodo * l2 = make(5, make(1, make(5, make(1, make(5, NULL)))));

  removeIf(&l1, l2, 2);

  /* show result */
  for (Nodo * l = l1; l != NULL; l = l->next)
    printf("%d ", l->d);
  putchar('\n');

  /* free resources */
  del(&l1);
  del(&l2);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra ll.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
4 4 4 7 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==3758== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3758== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3758== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3758== Command: ./a.out
==3758== 
4 4 4 7 
==3758== 
==3758== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3758==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3758==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 1,120 bytes allocated
==3758== 
==3758== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3758== 
==3758== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3758== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I understand my mistake.